# Как верно определить качество видео

Tags: python, видео, ffmpeg

В данный момент, для того чтобы определить качество видео, ориентируюсь на высоту кадра.

Многие из роликов имеют высокое качество, тогда когда высота кадра не велика.
К примеру качество видео 1080, а высота кадра 480. На выходе получим видео 144,240,360,480, то есть  видео в 720 и 1080, не станем конвертировать, так как высота менее...

Собственно, вопрос, как определить качество видео не ориентируясь на высоту кадру.

Comment: Никак. Качество видео — это субъективный параметр, который невозможно измерить. Объективно можно только сравнить с оригинальным несжатым видео (PSNR, SSIM, VMAF и прочие такие алгоритмы), а высота кадра и прочие характеристики видео здесь абсолютно ни при чём

Comment: Касательно конвертирования — просто не конвертируйте в больший размер кадра да и всё, здесь нет никакого смысла вводить странные термины вроде «качество видео»

Comment: Если действительно нужно, то можно попробовать оценить по качеству кадра, т.е. извлекаем произвольные кадры и ищем у них резкость границ (edge detection), скорее всего формула будет сложная понадобится еще учитывать разброс палитры на квадратных сэмплах, но вероятно на эту задачу можно натаскать нейронную сетку, но опять же, если это того стоит.

Comment: https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/kontrol-kachestva-video-metodom-opredeleniya-srednego-tsveta-kadra/viewer не думаю что это то, что вам нужно, но принцип описывающийся выше тут применяется.